# .htaccess rewrite for previous links challenge

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with my website links that previously were modified by .htaccess but now the links have changed as I have a new system

Previously I made links like this

http://example.com/1/computers/12/32/4003_apple_iphone_xr_reviews.html

where in this link "1" is country id "12" is category id "32" is subcategory id and "4003" is page id and "apple_iphone_xr" is the page title.

In the new system the links are like this

http://example.com/1/4003.html

where "1" is country id and "4003" is the page id.

I was wondering if there is any solution to redirect old URLs to these new ones?

Comment: show your .htaccess file code.

Comment: this is the htaccess code for this link I've had for more than 5 years  RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/computers/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html  index.php?view=product&id=$7&country=$1 [QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rewrite rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#define the base url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1] 

#redirect browser to a new url with 301 status
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\/computers/\d+\/\d+\/(\d+).* %{ENV:BASE}/$1/$2.html [L,R=301]

#rewrite url for php
RewriteRule ^(\d+)\/(\d+)\.html$ index.php?view=product&id=$2&country=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: I tried but no luck... this is the code that I had before RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/computers/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html  index.php?view=product&id=$7&country=$1 [QSA]  now the urls that were made by this code needs to be redirected to another links before in google search they are all indexed like the form I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be going in the right direction but the only problem is I see the server path in the url it redirects ... it will redirect to this http://example.com/home/user/public_html/1/4003.html

Comment: @Blake, I have added a base url to the first redirect. Does it work now?

Comment: @yurri-tvardyi yes it worked, thank you very much... you are the best